# Regression when size of explanatory variables differ in length/size

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, modeling, feature-extraction

What is generally considered the correct approach when you are performing a regression and your training data contains 'incidents' of some sort, but there may be a varying number of these items per training line?

To give you an example - suppose I wanted to predict the likelihood of accidents on a number of different roads. For each road, I may have a history multiple accidents and each accident will have its own different attributes (date (how recent), number of casualties, etc). How does one encapsulate all this information on one line?

You could for example assume a maximum of (say) ten and include the details of each as a separate input (date1, NoC1, date2, NoC2, etc....) but the problem is we want each item to be treated similarly and the model will treat items in column 4 as fundamentally separate from those in column 2 above, which it should not.

Alternatively we could include one row for each incident, but then any other columns in each row which are not related to these 'incidents' (such as age of road, width, etc) will be included multiple times and hence produce bias in the results.

What is the standard method that is use to accomplish this?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want a prediction per road or a prediction for all roads in total? If you want a prediction per road, you could take each accident as a sample. A similar question which might help you to predict when the next accident occurs: [Predict event based on previous ones](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16302/how-to-predict-when-the-next-event-occurs-based-on-times-of-previous-events)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robin. I really am after a prediction per road, but the problem is that there could be multiple accidents per road. And some roads may have had no accidents at all! So taking each accident as a sample wouldn't help as the road would not appear in the model (there could be other parameters related to the road which are not related to accidents, such as length, surface, etc). I am guessing what I really need is some sort of funky feature extraction here to condense all the accident informaiton into a number of column variables but how should one do that to minimise RSS?

Comment: Hm I don't really have a good answer, just something you can consider: How about training two different types of classifiers: **One for each road separately** (of course, they might have very little data per road) and the other is an **overall predictor, which uses all accidents** of all roads. The overall predictor could be used as a base estimation: How many accidents occur per road per month on average, are there months with more accidents etc. And the classifier per road is used to enhance the prediction per road. Though I don't know how to concretely combine these results.

Comment: I also suggest you compute some basic measurements like the average number of accidents/casualties per road/per month etc. and do some histogram plots. Maybe you get a better idea then.